# apt-get update Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, parallels

I'm having problems updating my Kali Linux VM. When I run

```
apt-get update
```

I get this error. How do I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your keyring keys are expired, you need to add them manualy or update the new keys.

to add a new key

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
```

to install the newest keys

```
apt-get install kali-archive-keyring
```